# How to define attributes on forms.ModelChoiceField?

Tags: django

Within my ModelForm I have created a dropdown that isn't bound to anything on the model directly. Hence I pass in the queryset for it upon instantiation.

```
class CallsForm(ModelForm): 
     def __init__(self, company, *args, **kwargs):
        super(CallsForm, self).__init__(*args, **kwargs)        
        self.fields['test_1'].queryset = company.deal_set.all() 

     test_1      =   forms.ModelChoiceField(queryset = '')
```

This works just fine. However how do I specify some attributes for it?

For the other model-bound-widgets I usually do this in Meta:

```
class Meta:
        model = Conversation
        widgets = {
                    'notes': forms.Textarea(attrs={'class': 'red'}),                    
                   }
```

But overriding it in my case would make no sense.

I tried to set the attributes upon instantiation without any luck.

```
test_1      =   forms.ModelChoiceField(attrs={'class':'hidden'}, queryset = '')
```

but it says:    `__init__() got an unexpected keyword argument 'attrs'`

Surely there must be a way...

Answer (score 30, accepted):

`attrs` is only valid on widgets, not fields. Try:

```
test_1 = forms.ModelChoiceField(queryset = '', widget=forms.Select(attrs={'class':'hidden'}))
```

Comment: In case you want to pass data to the code you don't fully control (`admin`), you can do so in `SomethingForm.__init__()`: `self.fields[name].widget.attrs = {...}` (or `update`). Or `widget.widget.attrs = {...}` in case of `django.contrib.admin.widgets.RelatedFieldWidgetWrapper`.